# ggplot2: drawing a area between two values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  value = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
  lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)
```

I want to plot the column "value" as a line and then an area that goes "under" which minimum point is lower and maximum point is upper.

So far I have this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(time, value, colour = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2)
```

But I don't want an error bar but an area, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `geom_ribbon()` function should provide the desired result.

```
df <- data.frame(
   time = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
   value = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
   group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
   upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
   lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6))

g<-ggplot(df, aes(time, value, colour = group, group = group)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2) +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill = group), alpha=0.5)

print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: @Paula, did this answer your question?